# Logger for WCF services

Tags: .net, wcf, logging, log4net-configuration

I want to make use of a logger in WCF service, which has two services exposed outside. And I want a daily based (every day new logger file based on date), also separate logger files for both services. which .NET loggers available I can go for, where above functionality can be implemented?

I tried using Log4Net. But i did not get how to change the log file names, other than what specified in config file, to suit my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example you could try. A rolling file appender. Will create a new file every 10MB. Will also generate new files when the date changes.

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="C:\\SomeFolder\\SomeFileName" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="-1" />
  <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="10MB" />
  <param name="RollingStyle" value="Composite" />
  <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false" />
  <param name="datePattern" value="yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%-7logger] [%-5level] [%5thread] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

If you want different things to go to different files, you could set up multiple appenders. Then, you'd associate specific log categories with specific appenders. There is an example of this here:-
[logging in log4net to different appenders based on circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677877/logging-in-log4net-to-different-appenders-based-on-circumstances)