# Suggestion for Output structure of Log4Net

Tags: c#, json, xml, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have implemented Log4Net for my C# application. I am required to save all the levels of logs. I am currently saving them into a txt file. However, after a while it is getting very hard to find a specific log inside the txt file. So I have to put the output file into a structure. I read about XML and JSON structures, but I could not decide which one is more efficient..

Question: Do you suggest me to use XML or JSON as the output structure, why? Or any other suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep the text format, but configure your log4net for better logging.
I always have more than 1 log file.

This is what I suggest:

1. Have a separated file for error/fatal
2. Have a log file for all of your logs so if you needed to see the debug/info logs after and before the error you look at that log
3. Filter your logs to show logs only for specific classes/assembly 
   like if you are using a CRM, it will print a lot of stuff that you don't want. like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677877/logging-in-log4net-to-different-appenders-based-on-circumstances).
4. Set log4net to put create different files every day (or if you have too much data every 10 MB)

Answer (score 0):

XML or JSON will make it even harder to read the logs directly due to the added clutter and escaping. **However** (that is a big emphasis), if you use JSON, you can then import your logs into [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/) (Elastic search, Logstash, Kibana stack). Going through the logs will be a breeze, then. You can use [log4net.Ext.Json](https://github.com/BrightOpen/log4net.Ext.Json/) to produce that JSON.

Like @Ashkan suggests, I'd keep the regular text file locally and stream JSON to a central store, such as ELK.